# mathutils.Matrix's position returns an empty vector instead of the actual position

Tags: scripting, transforms, quaternion

In 4x4 matrices, the values of the last row are usually the position, however in blender, when scripting returns 0, even though when i display the matrix on the console, the values are shown properly (Even applying the matrix to the object)

Here's what i do in the code

```
tfm = node.properties.transform
print(tfm)
dec = tfm.decompose()
print(dec)
```

decompose() returns 3 values, which are the position, rotation, and scale:

```
<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.9962,  0.0000, -0.0872, 0.0000)
            (-0.0000,  1.0000, -0.0000, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0872,  0.0000,  0.9962, 0.0000)
            ( 9.6625, 12.2470, 55.6297, 1.0000)>

(Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), 
Quaternion((0.9990482330322266, 7.4434889363317325e-09, -0.04361938312649727, -3.249897295720672e-10)), 
Vector((1.0, 1.0, 1.0)))
```

These are the results after decomposing, which is what is applied to the object in blender when i do:

```
obj.matrix_world = tfm
```

However, even though the object rotates, it does not move.

A workaroud for this is applying the position is this way:

```
obj.location = (tfm[3][0],tfm[3][1],tfm[3][2])
```

However i should not be doing this and i would like to straight up apply the matrix and get all the values properly. Am i using the wrong method? Or maybe library? I think i'm not getting the proper values, even scale and rotation wise.

Comment: Looks like you have a transposed matrix if you are expecting row 3 (instead of column 3) to be the location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As batFINGER said, the problem was that blender uses the matrices via rows instead columns, so i had to do the following to get the stuff right:

Doing this would fix it:

tfm.transpose()

Comment: I found this really helpful - thanks for taking the time to update. I think it's fine for you to click 'accept' on your own answer. That way when people are looking for an answer like this in a list, it will be flagged as answered.